# Changing views causes things on screen to appear

Tags: ios, swift, bar-chart, viewcontroller

Right now, I have a custom graph class which creates bar charts and displays them. However they only appear after I appear on the view controller twice. For eg. here I am on one of the view controllers that has the graph but it shows in an incomplete manner.

[image]

Then here I am at the same view controller but with the graph how it is meant to look like. As you can see, the bars have gotten longer and the dashed lines have appeared.

[image]

To achieve this, all I did was click on one of the tabs in the bottom and then clicked back on the tab for report and it changed the view. I really have no idea why this is happening and have been trying to tackle this for 2 days now. If someone can help me it would be great. Here is the code for a sample viewcontroller that shows the graph.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.21, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.18, green:0.21, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0)
    tupleArray.removeAll()
    newTuple.removeAll()
    filteredCategories.removeAll()
    categories.removeAll()
    self.categories = CoreDataHelper.retrieveCategories()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine
    UIColor(red:0.40, green:0.43, blue:0.48, alpha:1.0)
    currentYear1 = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date())!
    currentYear = String(describing: Calendar.current.component(.year, from: currentYear1))

    yearLabel.text = "\(currentYear)"
    if ExpensesAdditions().yearHasExpense(year: currentYear){
        noExpenseLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    else{
        tableView.isHidden = true
        barChartView.isHidden = true
        noExpenseLabel.isHidden = false
        totalSpentLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    totalSpent = ExpensesAdditions().retrieveYearlySum(year:currentYear)
    totalSpentLabel.text = "Total Spent: " + ExpensesAdditions().convertToMoney(totalSpent)
    for category in categories{
        if ExpensesAdditions().categoryinYearHasExpense(year:currentYear,category:category.title!){
            filteredCategories.append(category)
            tupleArray.append((category.title!,ExpensesAdditions().retrieveCategoryExpenseForYear(category: category.title!, year: currentYear)))
        }
        else{}
    }
    newTuple = tupleArray.sorted(by: { $0.1 > $1.1 })
    if ExpensesAdditions().yearHasExpense(year: currentYear){
        let dataEntries = generateDataEntries()
        barChartView.dataEntries = dataEntries
    }
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredCategories.count
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lastYearAnalysisCell") as! LastYearAnalysisViewTableViewCell
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    let row = indexPath.row
    let percentage:Double = (newTuple[row].1/totalSpent)*100
    let percentageDisplay:Int = Int(percentage.rounded())
    cell.nameLabel.text = newTuple[row].0
    cell.amountLabel.text = "(\(percentageDisplay)"+"%)     "+String(describing: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "chosenCurrencySymbol")!)+ExpensesAdditions().convertToMoney(newTuple[row].1)

    return cell
}
func generateDataEntries() -> [BarEntry] {

    let colors = [#colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1), #colorLiteral(red: 0.3647058904, green: 0.06666667014, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)]
    maximum = newTuple[0].1

    var result: [BarEntry] = []
    /// ---- Complicated Divising -------//////
    var maximumString:String = ExpensesAdditions().convertToMoney(maximum)
    var maximumInt:Int = Int(maximumString.getAcronyms())!
    let endIndex = maximumString.index(maximumString.endIndex, offsetBy: -3)
    let truncated = maximumString.substring(to: endIndex)
    if maximumInt < 5{
        divisor = Double((5*(pow(10, truncated.count - 1))) as NSNumber)
    }
    else if maximumInt > 5{
        divisor = Double((pow(10, truncated.count)) as NSNumber)
    }
    for i in 0..<filteredCategories.count {
        let value = ExpensesAdditions().convertToMoney(tupleArray[i].1)
        var height:Double = Double(value)! / divisor
        result.append(BarEntry(color: colors[i % colors.count], height: height, textValue: value, title: filteredCategories[i].title!))
    }
    return result
    //// --- Complicated Divising End -------- /////
}
```

If you need anymore code, please let me know and thanks in advance!

Here is the code for the bar chart entry code:

```
import UIKit

class BasicBarChart: UIView {

/// the width of each bar
let barWidth: CGFloat = 40.0

/// space between each bar
let space: CGFloat = 20.0

/// space at the bottom of the bar to show the title
private let bottomSpace: CGFloat = 40.0

/// space at the top of each bar to show the value
private let topSpace: CGFloat = 40.0

/// contain all layers of the chart
private let mainLayer: CALayer = CALayer()

/// contain mainLayer to support scrolling
private let scrollView: UIScrollView = UIScrollView()

var dataEntries: [BarEntry]? = nil {
    didSet {
        mainLayer.sublayers?.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperlayer()})

        if let dataEntries = dataEntries {
            scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: (barWidth + space)*CGFloat(dataEntries.count), height: self.frame.size.height)
            mainLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)

            drawHorizontalLines()

            for i in 0..<dataEntries.count {
                showEntry(index: i, entry: dataEntries[i])
            }
        }
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    setupView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    scrollView.layer.addSublayer(mainLayer)
    self.addSubview(scrollView)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
}

private func showEntry(index: Int, entry: BarEntry) {
    /// Starting x postion of the bar
    let xPos: CGFloat = space + CGFloat(index) * (barWidth + space)

    /// Starting y postion of the bar
    let yPos: CGFloat = translateHeightValueToYPosition(value: Float(entry.height))

    drawBar(xPos: xPos, yPos: yPos, color: entry.color)

    /// Draw text above the bar
    drawTextValue(xPos: xPos - space/2, yPos: yPos - 30, textValue: entry.textValue, color: entry.color)

    /// Draw text below the bar
    drawTitle(xPos: xPos - space/2, yPos: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace + 10, title: entry.title, color: entry.color)
}

private func drawBar(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    let barLayer = CALayer()
    barLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth, height: mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - yPos)
    barLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    mainLayer.addSublayer(barLayer)
}

private func drawHorizontalLines() {
    self.layer.sublayers?.forEach({
        if $0 is CAShapeLayer {
            $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    })
    let horizontalLineInfos = [["value": Float(0.0), "dashed": true], ["value": Float(0.5), "dashed": true], ["value": Float(1.0), "dashed": true]]
    for lineInfo in horizontalLineInfos {
        let xPos = CGFloat(0.0)
        let yPos = translateHeightValueToYPosition(value: (lineInfo["value"] as! Float))
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPos, y: yPos))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width, y: yPos))
        let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        lineLayer.path = path.cgPath
        lineLayer.lineWidth = 0.5
        if lineInfo["dashed"] as! Bool {
            lineLayer.lineDashPattern = [4, 4]
        }
        lineLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1).cgColor
        self.layer.insertSublayer(lineLayer, at: 0)
    }
}

private func drawTextValue(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, textValue: String, color: UIColor) {
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth+space, height: 22)
    textLayer.foregroundColor = color.cgColor
    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    textLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0).fontName as CFString, 0, nil)
    textLayer.fontSize = 14
    textLayer.string = textValue
    mainLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
}

private func drawTitle(xPos: CGFloat, yPos: CGFloat, title: String, color: UIColor) {
    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: barWidth + space, height: 22)
    textLayer.foregroundColor = color.cgColor
    textLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    textLayer.font = CTFontCreateWithName(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 0).fontName as CFString, 0, nil)
    textLayer.fontSize = 14
    textLayer.string = title
    mainLayer.addSublayer(textLayer)
}

private func translateHeightValueToYPosition(value: Float) -> CGFloat {
    let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(value) * (mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - topSpace)
    return mainLayer.frame.height - bottomSpace - height
}
}
```

Comment: How do you set the size of the bar chart view?

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, it is set using the BarChartEntry Class. I will link up the code for you to see.

Comment: Sorry if I am unclear. I mean how/where do you set the size on the barChartView? Is it in storyboard or code? If code, in what function?

Comment: It is in the generateBarEntries function. Where I set the variable height to equal to a value.

Comment: I cannot see that function. At what stage is that called? `viewDidLoad()` or somewhere else? What is it set to?
I am asking because I think your problems relates to layout issues. Your bar chart seems to have the wrong height in the first picture.

Comment: Sorry it's called generateDataEntries. It's called in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you set up your bar chart in `viewWillAppear`, at which point the final size of the view has not been set yet. To fix this you must either delay setting the data until in `viewDidAppear`, or you need to trigger a redraw of the bars and dashed lines when the frame size has changed i.e. from `layoutSubviews`.

One point of advice I want to share with you is that you should try to separate your code so that sizing and positioning of all the view's sub-items are done in `layoutSubviews`, and the actual adding and removal of them are done elsewhere.

Update:

In your class `BasicBarChart` you should try to separate adding the chart elements, and do the actual sizing of the elements. This is because sizing is an event that often occurs more than once, especially when using auto-layout.

If your `BasicBarChart` view is set up with constraints, it will usually receive at least two different sizes during setup, once with the sizes in your storyboard file, and once with the actual device derived sizes. Since you don't want to add everything more than once, you should do the adding elsewhere. A good place could be during initialization or when setting data.

The sizing of a view's sub-elements is best done in its `layoutSubviews()` function. You have already started! Just move over the sizing of your other elements here too, and everything should work much better.

```
class BasicBarChart: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        // Size and position bars, labels and dashed lines here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I implemented your solution of adding the code to viewDidAppear and it worked for 2 of my views, but not the 3rd one. Could you please elaborate on your second solution of triggering a redraw in layoutSubviews?

Comment: Great you are on your way! I added more to the solution.